# window.location problem

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-6

I am facing on strange problem in ie6.

When i am using window.location to redirect page through javascript it works fine in all browser except ie6.

It works in ie 6 if i place just like below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:window.location('http://www.demo.com');">demo</a>
```

but its not working for below code.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:redirect();>demo</a>
function redirect()
{
  window.location('http://www.demo.com');"
}
```

can you please figure out that whats problem here.

Thanks.

Avinash

Answer (score 7):

The `javascript:` protocol is only used if you have Javascript code in an URL. If you put it in an event handler it becomes a label instead.

The `location` member is not a function, it's an object. Set the `href` property to change the location.

You have an extra quotation mark after the code line in the function, which is probably causing a syntax error.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="redirect();>demo</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect() {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.demo.com';
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Guffa: Setting window.location will still work.  Try it: `window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";`.  Good spot on the syntax error though, I must admit I overlooked it :)

Comment: @Andy: Assigning the url to the location object only works in some browsers.

Comment: @Guffa: Ah, fair enough.  I would be interested to know which (if any) of the top browsers it wouldn't work in, though.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="redirect(); return false;">
  demo
</a>
```

Comment: @aaron, I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Aaron: Where did he say that window.location was a function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the page to redirect to `demo.html` when the user clicks a link, dare I suggest you use the universal, crossbrowser `<a href="demo.html">demo</a>`?

Comment: @Phil: You don't think it's likely that the code he wrote in the question is just a simplified example of what he's trying to do?

Comment: @Andy E: Yes, but he hasn't shown us that. If he wants a js function to change the window location, that would be a different question - the specific example was a redirect in a hyperlink. A less simplified question might help - making javascript run when the user clicks a link is not the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.demo.com';
```

in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

window.event.returnValue = false;
      document.location.href='http://www.demo.com';