# How to download PDF File Generated from TCPDF (PHP) using AJAX (jQuery)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, tcpdf

I am using Yii Framework, TCPDF and jQuery to generate a pdf.

The pdf is generated by inputing in a form and submitting it using ajax.

The pdf is created but here is the problem when it returns to the client, it down not download.

here is the php code

`$pdf->Output('Folder Label.pdf','D');`

the jQuery on success function has

`success: function(data) {
 window.open(data);
}`

Which i got from this site.

Can you please help

Comment: what does " it down not download." mean?

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is that you are not getting the browser's download dialog for the PDF, then the solution is to do it this way:

First, redirect the browser (using `window.location` as the other answers say) to navigate to a special controller action in your application, e.g. with this url: `http://your.application.com/download/pdf/filename.pdf`.

Implement the action referenced in the URL like this:

```
public function actionPdf() {
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf";');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize('path/to/pdf'));
    readfile('path/to/pdf');
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

This will cause the browser to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the PDF to somewhere on your server and then issue `window.location = '/url/to/pdf-you-just-saved.pdf';` from your javascript. The users browser will then prompt them to download the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, that will cause errors on some browsers, [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp) is the correct way to set the window location.

```
window.location.assign( downloadUrlToPdf );
```

So

1. Send a request to make the pdf via Ajax to the server
2. Process and generate the pdf on the server
3. Return in the Ajax call the url to the file you just made
4. Use the above code fragment to open a download of said file

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location Specifically "newLocation is a Location object or a **string**, specifying the URL to navigate to." List the browsers that have an issue with `window.location = '';` please.

Comment: @Treffynnon - Simple: Internet Explorer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939332/window-location-problem

Comment: I have never had an issue with this in IE7+. However I have not supported IE6 for a long time and neither do my clients or their users. http://ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @Treffynnon If only all developers had such freedom. Frankly IE6 is a gaffe factory. You should count yourself lucky.

Answer (score 0):

in tcpdf ,  just pass this argument the Output method:

```
$pdf->Output('yourfilename.pdf', 'D');
```

that's all

Comment: The OP specifies AJAX. AJAX is generally used to bring in content without reloading the page - in otherwords, there is probably content already outputted. TCPDF will (as I have just seen in my situation) generate an error when you try to output with content already outputted: `TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file`