# Download PDF Using AJAX and TCPDF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, tcpdf

I am trying to make a post via AJAX to a PHP script that will then create a PDF.

```
function getPDF() {
    var hashed_center_ids = JSON.parse($('#hashed_center_ids').val());

    var print_data = $('.print-options:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=site_url('front_office/get_pdf/')?>",
        data: {hashed_center_ids : hashed_center_ids, print_data : print_data},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            var blob=new Blob([response]);
            var link=document.createElement('a');
            link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download="test"+new Date()+".pdf";
            link.click();
        }
    });
}
```

Once my PDF has been created I return it like so:

`return $pdf;`

However this just returns,

`Message:  Object of class TCPDF could not be converted to string`

in the chrome console.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I would post the code where $pdf is created and/or assigned and the line where you're getting the error.  It's tough to say from what we see here.

Comment: That error is coming from server not the javascript

Comment: I think he's trying to pass the raw binary data into `response`, and then tries to make it work as a downloadable link - kind of an odd approach, because this essentially makes user download the content *twice*.

Comment: @Nic, you should try solutions offered in the "Related" section here, such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500485/how-to-download-pdf-file-generated-from-tcpdf-php-using-ajax-jquery), for instance.